# Creating a responsive navbar using React whenever I try to open the sidebar using three dot button on bottom navigation I don't see anything happening

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, responsive-design

```
              import React, { useState } from 'react'
              import './Navbar.scss'

              // ICONS
              import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';
              import LocalMallOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalMallOutlined';
              import PersonOutlineOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlineOutlined';
              import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
              import HomeOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HomeOutlined';
              import MoreHorizOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreHorizOutlined';
              import CloseOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CloseOutlined';
              import LoginIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Login';
              import LogoutIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Logout';
              import AssignmentIndIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AssignmentInd';
              import Login from '@mui/icons-material/Login';
              import Logout from '@mui/icons-material/Logout';
              import WhatshotIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Whatshot';
              import MailOutlined from '@mui/icons-material/MailOutlined';
              import CategoryOutlined from '@mui/icons-material/CategoryOutlined';

              const Navbar = () => {


                // NAVBAR TOOGLE MENU
                const[open,setOpen] = useState(true);

                const handleOpen = ()=>{
                  console.log("hello")
                  setOpen(!open);
                }

                return (
                  <div className='navbar'>
                    <div className="container">
                          <div className="left">
                              <h1 className='logo'>urbane</h1>
                          </div>
                          <div className="center">
                              <div className="item">Home</div>
                              <div className="item">About</div>
                              <div className="item">Hot Offers</div>
                              <div className="item">Contact</div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="right">
                                <PersonOutlineOutlinedIcon className='profile'/>
                                <div className='fav-Icon'>
                                <FavoriteBorderIcon className='fav'/>
                                <span>2</span>
                                </div>
                                <div className='cart-Icon'>
                                <LocalMallOutlinedIcon className='cart'/>
                                <span>1</span>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='bottom-menu'>
                              <div className='bottom-icon' onClick={handleOpen}>
                              <HomeOutlinedIcon fontSize='large'/>
                              </div>
                              <div className='bottom-icon'>
                              <FavoriteBorderIcon fontSize='large'/>
                              </div>
                              <div className='bottom-icon'>
                              <LocalMallOutlinedIcon fontSize='large'/>
                              </div>
                              <div className='bottom-icon'>
                              <MoreHorizOutlinedIcon fontSize='large'/>
                              </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={open ? `side-menu open-side-menu`:`side-menu`}>
                          <div className="side-menu-top">
                              <h1 className='logo'>urbane</h1>
                              <div className='close' onClick={handleOpen}>
                              <CloseOutlinedIcon fontSize='large'/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="side-menu-items">
                              <div className="side-menu-item">
                              <WhatshotIcon/>
                              Hot Offers
                              </div>
                              <div className="side-menu-item">
                              <CategoryOutlined/>
                              Products
                              </div>
                              <div className="side-menu-item">
                              <MailOutlined/>
                              Contact
                              </div>
                              <div className='side-menu-item'>
                                  <LoginIcon/>
                                  <p>Login</p>
                              </div>
                              <div className='side-menu-item'>
                                  <AssignmentIndIcon/>
                                  <p>Sign Up</p>
                              </div>
                              <div className='side-menu-item'>
                                <LogoutIcon/>
                                <p>Logout</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )
              }

              export default Navbar
```

```
                $spanish-gray: hsl(0, 0%, 60%);
                $sonic-silver: hsl(0, 0%, 47%);
                $eerie-black: hsl(0, 3%, 7%);
                $salmon-pink: hsl(353, 100%, 78%);
                $sandy-brown: hsl(29, 90%, 65%);
                $bittersweet: hsl(0, 100%, 70%);
                $ocean-green: hsl(152, 51%, 52%);
                $davys-gray: hsl(0, 0%, 33%);
                $cultured: hsl(0, 0%, 93%);
                $white: hsl(0, 100%, 100%);
                $onyx: hsl(0, 0%, 27%);

                @mixin mobile{
                    @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
                        @content;
                    }
                }

                @mixin tablet{
                    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
                        @content;
                    }
                }

                @mixin laptop{
                    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
                        @content;
                    }
                }

                .navbar{
                    height: 70px;

                    
                    .container{
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                        justify-content:space-between;
                        max-width: 1100px;
                        margin:0px auto;
                        padding: 12px 20px;
                        @include mobile{
                            padding: 10px 15px;
                        }

                        .left{ 
                            h1{
                                font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
                            }
                            @include tablet{
                                width: 100%;
                                text-align: center;
                            }
                        }

                        .center{
                        display: flex;
                        gap: 40px;
                        font-weight: bold;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        font-size: 17px;
                        color: $davys-gray;
                        @include tablet{
                            display: none;
                        }
                        @include mobile{
                            display: none;
                        }


                        .item{
                            cursor: pointer;
                        }
                        }

                        .right{
                            display: flex;
                            gap: 20px;

                            .fav,.profile,.cart{
                                font-size: 30px;
                                cursor: pointer;
                            }

                            .cart-Icon,.fav-Icon{
                                position: relative;
                                span{
                                    font-size: 14px;
                                    font-weight: bold;
                                    position: absolute;
                                    width: 20px;
                                    height: 20px;
                                    border-radius: 50%;
                                    color: white;
                                    background-color:$salmon-pink;
                                    display: flex;
                                    align-items: center;
                                    justify-content: center;
                                    top: -7px;
                                    right: -8px;
                                }
                            }
                            @include tablet{
                                display: none;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .bottom-menu{
                        z-index: 1;
                        visibility: hidden;
                        width: 100%;
                        position:fixed;
                        padding: 10px;
                        right: 0;
                        bottom: 0;
                        height: 55px;
                        width:100%;
                        display: flex;
                        align-items:center;
                        justify-content:center;
                        gap: 40px;
                        background-color:white;

                        @include tablet{
                            visibility: visible;
                        }

                        .bottom-icon{
                            cursor: pointer;
                        }
                    }


                    // SIDE MENU

                    .side-menu{
                        display: none;
                        visibility: hidden;
                        position:fixed;
                        width: 70%;
                        padding: 30px 60px;
                        z-index: 2;
                        top: 0;
                        left: -100%;
                        height: 100vh;
                        background-color:$eerie-black;
                        color: white;
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        align-items:flex-start;
                        justify-content: space-around;
                        transition:all 1s ease-in-out;

                        @include tablet{
                        
                            &.open-side-menu{
                            visibility: visible;
                            display: flex;
                            left: 0%;

                            }
                        }

                        .side-menu-top{
                            width: 100%;
                            display: flex;
                            align-items: center;
                            gap: 30px;
                            justify-content: space-between;
                            font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
                            .close{
                                cursor: pointer;
                            }
                        }

                        .side-menu-items{
                            display: flex;
                            flex-direction: column;
                            align-items: flex-start;
                            justify-content: center;
                            gap: 30px;
                            font-size: 20px;
                            font-weight: 500;

                            .side-menu-item{
                                display: flex;
                                gap: 10px;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

When I click on the three dots in bottom navigation, I don't see anything happening.
When I change the true false value of open variable.

Initially It looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJVtm.png)

When I click on the three dot button in bottom navigation it should look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8CnC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `handleChange` on-click handler is binded in the wrapper of `HomeOutlinedIcon`:

```
<div className='bottom-icon' onClick={handleOpen}>
  <HomeOutlinedIcon fontSize='large'/>
</div>
```

You should bind the `handleOpen` function to the wrapper of `MoreHorizOutlinedIcon`, if you want to show the pop up by clicking the three dots.